# django 1.9: enabling ssl

Tags: django, ssl

I would like my site to be on https://

I read up on stuff and followed instructions such as adding the following in settings.py:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
```

but it doesnt seem to work

when i put, https:// in front of my site address, i get an error:

```
SSL Not Enabled

This site is not enabled for SSL. Please follow this link to visit the site without SSL.
```

1. how do i redirect all http requests to https://
2. with ssl, do i need to buy ssl certificate from commerical? If so, what do i do with those keys to have my django site use it?

Comment: typically this is handled from your web server, Apache or Nginx, you can't have this working (to my knowledge) on the `runserver` command line. You can use self signed certificates, but users will get a warning each time they visit. so a commercial one is best. again, that is installed on the web server, not django.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache or Nginx you will have to look at the documentation.

For testing and development you can install django-sslserver quite easily
See:
http://www.marinamele.com/2014/09/security-on-django-app-https-everywhere.html

And create a self signed certificate if you need one, it is only good for testing though see 
[How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl) or get a free one from https://letsencrypt.org/ which may suit you needs for production.